# Xcode 8: Interface builder shows different color that set

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, colors, interface-builder

Take a look at the picture below:

[image]

This is the same hex used in both places #28647B. 
The lower part is set from code and appears to reflects the color properly:

```
let proxy = UIPageControl.appearance()
proxy.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
proxy.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
proxy.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 40.0/255.0, green: 100.0/255.0, blue: 123.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

The upper part is set in interface builder.

I checked all other layers, opacity parameters etc and found nothing that can change the way this color look.

Now interesting part, I inspected both colors using HexColor mac app, this is the result:

for upper part:

[image]

Not sure what does it mean that RGB factors vary from the correct ones, but result is correct

Now, time to inspect the lower part:

[image]

This time RGB looks good but results is different.

Now it's the best part:

**When I set the background color from code as I did in appearance proxy, it works fine. Is something interface builder speciffic that changes the visible shade of background color? How can one rely on colors set in Interface Builder?**

Comment: it probably has something to do with the fact that Apple introduced the wider color space. I suggest you look into that.

Comment: I have the same problem. did you found a fix for it?

Comment: Unfortunately not, still waiting for the answer

Comment: I have the same problem. In my case, UIButton

Comment: @LukasPetr I also think about that. In the interface builder, color space can be selected by clicking wheel button on the right side of dropdown menu. But how could do that in code?

Comment: @LukasPetr you're right: by default Interface Builder uses Generic RGB, while on device it's Device RGB.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Same problem in my projects, I solved this issue choosing "Device RGB" and not "Generic RGB". Some. time the color not change , move opacity and the color will set.
see the image:

[image]

Comment: @DCDC I think it should be sRGB from iOS 10 and onward. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/1621925-init "On applications linked for iOS 10 or later, the color is specified in an extended range sRGB color space. On earlier versions of iOS, the color is specified in a device RGB colorspace."

Answer (score 2):

If you make an Asset Catalog, and add your colours in there, you can enter them as.

Devices: Universal
Content: sRGB
Input Method: 8-bit Hexadecimal

Add all your app colours in this way, and reference them by their Asset Catalog names, and all Hex Values will be preserved and displayed correctly.